# Why the use of the ID alone is insufficient as a partition key?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

In my application (mostly read oriented), i didn't set any partition key, so by default it will use the id as partition key. According to graph, we have a hot partition.

[image]

Storage for all the collections (collection that hitting Max RU is the second collection, 149.7 MiB one)
[image]

Why the use of the ID alone is insufficient as a partition key? i thought id is unique and it will scale evenly.

Comment: How big is your collection, exactly?

Comment: @Dai, i updated the question for collection size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a hot partition. A hot partition means that one or a few partitions use a high amount of RU compared to other partitions. In your case you have so little data that all your logical partitions reside into a single physical partitions. Thus it's not a hot partition; It's just a single partition that makes most of its RU throughput.

Having the `id` as partition key is also no issue. Preferably you have a property that can act as partition key that you often query over. If you have no property that's suitable using the `id` as partition key is no issue at all. By definition the `id` partition key should be unlikely to cause hot partitions as your items are 'randomly' split between physical partitions once your collections get big enough to cause the splits.

Comment: wow, thanks for answering, so for my case, i just have to increase the RU capacity right?

Comment: @hades That depends. As long as your RU consumption is high, but you don't experience any problems your throughput is ideal. A general rule of thumb by Microsoft is 1-5% of your requests resulting in 429 errors to fully utilize your RU/s. Ultimately it's up to you to decide what's acceptable. In case you experience problems the solution would be to increase RU throughput. If possible you could also look at enabling the 'burst capacity' feature to handle short bursts of increased RU (at no additional cost) if you haven't already done so.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but my RU/s exceed 4000, so i think i can't make use of the burst capacity right?

Comment: @hades No; that would've been a nice bonus if you were below the threshold, but in your case not usable.